# Any element in $K/\mathbb Q_p$ can be generated by some $\pi \in K$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory, ramification

following a sentence from "p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis and Zeta-functions" by Neal Koblitz, page 66:

Let $\pi \in K$ where $K$ is an extension field of $\mathbb Q_p$ (the p-adic rationals) and $ord_p(\pi)=\frac 1 e$ where $e$ is the index of ramification.
Then any $x \in K$ can be written uniquely in the form $\pi^mu$ where $|u|_p=1$ and $m \in \mathbb Z$.

Can you please help me understand why that is right?

Is it because of $e$ being the ramification index and so $ord_p(\pi)=min_{x \in K}(ord_p(x))$?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it on my own so I might as well share the solution..

Since $ord_p(\pi)=min_{x \in K}(ord_p(x))$, $\pi$ has the smallest p-adic valuation. hence, we can multiply it by any $u$ (with $|u|_p=1$), or by itself, to get any nonzero element of K.

**Edited:**

Given $a \in K$.
$ord_p$ function's image is $\frac{1}{e}\mathbb Z$ (prove it). Hence, $ord_p(a)=\frac m e$. So one can write $a=\pi^mu$ where $u=\frac{a}{\pi^m}$ and hence the uniqueness of this form.

Comment: It's not true that $ord_p(\pi)=min_{x \in K}(ord_p(x))$. Rather, $ord_p(\pi)=min_{x \in K: ord_p(x) > 0}(ord_p(x))$. Besides, I'm not sure if your answer really shows understanding of why the statement is true.

Comment: Regarding the first part of your comment, you're right. Regarding the second part, please enlight me

Comment: $\pi$ has the smallest strictly positive valuation, it remains to show the valuation exists and is discrete valued to obtain that $\pi$ exists and for any $x$ there is $m\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $v(x) = m v(\pi)$. For this a concrete way is to embed $K$ in its Galois closure $L/\Bbb{Q}_p$ and set $v(x) = v(\sigma(x))$ so that $v(x) = \frac{1}{[L:\Bbb{Q}_p]} v(\prod_{\sigma \in Gal(L/\Bbb{Q}_p)} \sigma(x))$. Another way is to choose a maximal ideal ( above $(p)$) on $O_K$ the integral closure of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ and show the valuation doesn't depend on the chosen maximal ideal.